# Redux Toolkit AsyncThunk dispatch

Tags: redux, frontend, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

Can I access **dispatch** inside **extraReducers**? I want to **dispatch** action based of the asyncThunk function, if it failed or completed.

```
const todosSlice = createSlice({
    name: "todos",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        console.log(builder);
        builder.addCase(fetchTodos.pending, (state) => {
            return { ...state, isFetching: true };
        });
        builder.addCase(fetchTodos.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            return { ...state, isFetching: false, data: action.payload.data };
        });
        builder.addCase(fetchTodos.rejected, (state, action) => {
            console.log("Can console here if reject occurs");
            return { ...state, isFetching: false, error: action.error };
        });
    },
});

export const todosSliceState = (state) => state.todos;

export default todosSlice.reducer;
```

So i want to dispath action inside **fetchTodos.fulfilled** and that action will just shange state of other reduxSlice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I access `dispatch` inside `extraReducers`? I want to dispatch
> action based of the asyncThunk function, if it failed or completed.

No, since reducers are pure functions, they can't have side-effects like dispatching other actions.

Just add `fetchTodos.fulfilled` as a reducer case in the other slice/reducer that has the state you would like to update.

Alternatively you could also dispatch actions from the `fetchTodos` action, which are handled in other reducers, based on the success/failure of some asynchronous logic.

Example:

```js
const fetchTodos = createAsyncThunk(
  "fetchTodos",
  async (arg, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      ... asynchronous fetch logic
      thunkApi.dispatch(someAction(somePayload));           // <-- success
      return someValue;
    } catch(error) {
      thunkApi.dispatch(someOtherAction(someOtherPayload)); // <-- failure
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Wow, i knew u can do it with thunkApi as thet 2nd parameter in fetchTodos.
But i would have never guessed i can put extraReducers.fullfilled case from this slice to another slice, eye opening. Thanks

Comment: @NikonGeorge Yes, they *are* just action types, and any reducer can react/respond to any dispatched action. Has this answer helped address/resolve your question/issue?